# Cart page woocommerce doesn’t updating

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Since a few days, I can’t update nis to delete an item on my shopping cart. I have deactivated the cache and the problem is still there. These last days I added the CDN option.
I already have this two lignes in woocommerce/cart/cart.php

```
<?php do_action(‘woocommerce_cart_actions’); ?> 
<?php wp_nonce_field(‘woocommerce-cart’, ‘woocommerce-cart-nonce’); ?
```

**I have already read the subjects of the same problem but no solution is proposed!**

Can you bring me a solution?

Sincerely

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Cart page is ajax call.

Comment: The log shows no errors! I tried everything from changing the theme, disabling plugins, deleting woocommerce and putting an older version. I have tried everything.

Comment: I found this error on the woocommerce log

https://ibb.co/X8JBfqG